# Why does geom_smooth() automatically excludes some values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I make a ggplot2 graphic like this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=timepoint, y=y, size=Status, shape=Status)) + 
            geom_point(fill="red") + 
            geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, size=1, linetype="twodash") +
            facet_grid(Test ~ Batch, scales="free_y")
```

And it gives:
[image]

There are other options in my code to control legend appearance, etc, but nowhere I have asked `geom_smooth()` to exclude some values, and as you can see it automatically excludes the points having `Status=="FAIL"` !

You can generate such a plot without the other options (but showing the same problem) with the following dataframe:

```
dat <- structure(list(Test = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("PH", 
"ANTIGENIC ACTIVITY BY ELISA", "WATER CONTENT BY µKARL FISCHER"
), class = "factor"), Batch = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("HB07", 
"HB08"), class = "factor"), timepoint = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3), Status = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PASS", "FAIL"), class = "factor"), y = c(11.7, 
12.7, 12.8, 17.6, 8.6, 9.6, 16.5, 15.4, 10.1, 9, 11.7, 12.5, 
7.9, 9.3, 15.5, 14.7, 12.9, 10.8, 14.5, 16.5)), .Names = c("Test", 
"Batch", "timepoint", "Status", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? Would be easier if we could play with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By providing the shape aes you group the data. If the group consists only of one member, `geom_smooth` cannot print anything for that group.

Possibly you want this:

```
geom_smooth(aes(shape=NA),method=lm, se=FALSE, size=1, linetype="twodash")
```

Comment: Thanks, I see ! I didn't know that the shape aes is considered as a grouping !